# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x}e^{\frac{x}{1+x}}-\frac{1}{\sin x}\right)^{\frac{1}{\arctan x}} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x}e^{\frac{x}{1+x}}-\frac{1}{\sin x}\right)^{\frac{1}{\arctan x}} $$

Honestly I don't know whether I'm on the right track.

My attempt (by using brute force):

I left for later that of raising to $e$ and began with the parenthesis first:

$$\frac{1}{x}e^{\frac{x}{1+x}}-\frac{1}{\sin x} = \frac{\sin xe^{\frac{x}{1+x}}-x}{x\sin x}$$

(Here for convenience I'll skip the little-$o$ notation):

$$e^{\frac{x}{1+x}} = 1 + \frac{x}{1+x}$$

$$\sin x = x - \frac{x^3}{6}$$

So

\begin{align*}
\sin x e^{\frac{x}{1+x}} & = \left(x - \frac{x^3}{6}\right) \left(1 + \frac{x}{1+x}\right) \\ & = x + \frac{x^2}{1+x} - \frac{x^3}{6} +...
\end{align*}

and

$$x\sin x = x^2 - \frac{x^4}{6}$$

Then

\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin xe^{\frac{x}{1+x}}-x}{x\sin x} &= \frac{x + \frac{x^2}{1+x} - \frac{x^3}{6}-x}{x^2 - \frac{x^4}{6}}\\
&= \frac{x^2 \left( \frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{x}{6} \right)}{x^2 \left(1-\frac{x^2}{6}\right)}\\
&= \frac{5-x}{(1+x)(6-x^2)}
\end{align*}

And with $\frac{1}{\arctan x}$ I dont' what to do. Is there a way to calculate its Maclaurin Series without taking  the derivative successively?

Comment: This is one of the ugliest, most nightmarish limits I've ever seen in this site....and I've been around for a while. Is this homework, something you came up with, did this appear somewhere...?

Comment: @DonAntonio It's one of the limits of my homework. It's from a book of exercises on mathematical analysis that we use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the log an then decompose

$$\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}e^{\frac{x}{1+x}}-\frac{1}{\sin x}\right)}{\arctan x}$$
$$=\frac{x}{\arctan x}\frac{\ln \left(\frac{1}{x}e^{\frac{x}{1+x}}-\frac{1}{\sin x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}e^{\frac{x}{1+x}}-\frac{1}{\sin x}-1}\left[
\frac{e^{\frac{x}{1+x}}-1-x}{x^2}+\frac{1-\frac{x}{\sin x}}{x^2}\right]$$
 now evaluate limits of all the parts separately.

For example

$$\frac{e^{\frac{x}{1+x}}-1-x}{x^2}=\frac{e^{\frac{x}{1+x}}-e^x}{x^2}+\frac{e^{x}-1-x}{x^2}$$
The limit of $\frac{e^{x}-1-x}{x^2}$ is easy or well known.
For the other term
$$\frac{e^{\frac{x}{1+x}}-e^x}{x^2}=e^x\frac{e^{\frac{x^2}{1+x}}-1}{x^2}$$
Now $e^x\to 1$ For the other factor I wrote it as
$$\frac{1}{x+1}\frac{e^{\frac{x^2}{1+x}}-1}{\frac{x^2}{x+1}}$$

$\frac{1}{x+1}\to 1$ and what remains is $\frac{e^y-1}{y}$ by a change of variable $y=\frac{x^2}{x+1}$. So everything reduces to standard limits.

You should get a limit of $-\frac{2}{3}$, if I havent made a mistake.

Comment: The log of the original expression is *not* what you wrote in the second line: there must be a $\;log\;$ acting on the whole numerator there.

Comment: Edited better ?

Comment: @Re Now it is fine, but how did you pass from that line to the following one? Did you do l'Hospital (without the limit...), or what? Anyway, it still doesn't look much less monstruous...am I missing something?

Comment: @DonAntonio To answer your last question: yes.

Comment: Well, perhaps the OP will have a much better insight than myself...thanks.

Comment: Finally I got what you've pointed out. And yes the answer is $-2/3$ (well $e^{-2/3}$). The first two factors go to $1$, So we work with the rightmost one. Here I have one doubt: when working with the first rightmost fraction (that involving $e$) I expanded the exponential into $1 + x/(1+x)$ and after cancelling out gives $-1$, which it turn leads to a limit of $-7/6$. But after expanding it into $1 + x/(1+x) + x^2/[2(1+x)^2]$, it gives $-1/2$, which finally leads to the right answer. So my question is (comment below):

Comment: How can one know how many terms have a function to be expanded into? it's obvious that it has to be into the necessary terms in order to get rid of the $x$ in the denominator, but at first glance here $1 + x/(1+x)$ works just fine. What do I have to take into account?

Comment: @Jazz Glad you understand it. I am not doing expansions. For example $e^{\frac{x}{x+1}}-1-x=(e^{\frac{x}{x+1}}-e^x)+(e^x-1-x)$, then again each term can be evaluated. Basically I am reducing by pulling off expressions whose limits I know.

Comment: That's cool. I've been trying to do that own my own, but I wasn't able ):. Please, could you make me the favor of showing completely what you've described just for one factor (say, \frac{e^{\frac{x}{x+1}}-1-x}{x^2})? I'm new on this of limits and Taylor things (:. Whatever I do to that term I end up with either $-1$ or $0$.

Comment: I meant for $\frac{e^{\frac{x}{x+1}}-1-x}{x^2}$ (forgot to insert the dollar sign above)

Comment: @Jazz I edited the answer since its too much to put into a comment.

Comment: Sorry for not thanking you earlier, but I got no notification of your comment above. I see now. It better put myself to learn those limits.